# Overlapping Header/Section

Tags: html, css

I have a header and section where elements in header are overlapping. Specifically, two divs inside header are overlapping (one's floated left, the other floated right)

HTML:

```
        <div id="main-contianer">
        <header id="main">
            <div id="logo">
                <h1>Ladder</h1>
            </div>

            <div id="sign-in">
                <form id="log-in" action="login.jsp"><!--not complete-->
                    <div id="username">
                        <label>Username</label>
                        <input type="text" name="username">
                    </div>
                    <div id="password">
                        <label>Password</label>
                        <input type="password" name="password">
                    </div>
                    <div id="log-in">
                        <input type="submit" value="Log In">
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </header>
        <section>
            <!--code here not included-->
        </section>
```

CSS:

```
header#main div#logo{
    float: left;
}

header#main div#sign-in{
    float: right;
}
```

Here is the JSFiddle to see what it looks like: http://jsfiddle.net/FLwUA/106/

How do I ensure that header and section don't overlap?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: If you want the text from section to appear below the form and not append right under.. you can add `<div style="clear:both;"></div>` after `</header>`

Answer (score 0):

try using `position: relative` instead of float.

then give `display: inline-block;`

Answer (score 0):

Add a new class in CSS as:

**CSS**

```
.clearfix {
  clear: both;
}
```

After `</header>` but before `<section>` add the following in HTML

**HTML**

```
<div class="clearfix"></div>
```

Refer [here](https://jsfiddle.net/shashank2691/s3jqn1f0/).